# How can I use JQuery to add a decimal and trailing zeros to currency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-conversion

I have checked all related questions and none, fully address my question.  I know how to convert to money with symbols and commas, but not sure how to add trailing zeros if the user did not specify cents.

I did come across a post that mentioned adding this .toFixed(2) but I do not understand how to incorporate that into my function.

Desired function is 14578 to convert to $14,578.00 but do not add the zeros if the number were 14578.79 to $14,578.79.  Also I noticed that it puts a dollar sign in the field even if left blank.  Any way to avoid that?

```js
$('.money').blur(function(e){        
    $(this).val(formatCurrency(this.value.replace(/[,$]/g,'')));
}).on('keypress',function(e){
    if(!$.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) e.preventDefault();
}).on('paste', function(e){    
    var cb = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;      
    if(!$.isNumeric(cb.getData('text'))) e.preventDefault();
});
function formatCurrency(number){
    var n = number.split('').reverse().join("");
    var n2 = n.replace(/\d\d\d(?!$)/g, "$&,");    
    return '$' + n2.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class="money"/>
<input type='text'/>
<input type='text' class="money"/>
<input type='text'/>
<input type='text' class="money"/>
<input type='text'/>
<input type='text' class="money"/>
<input type='text'/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: An immediate problem I see with this is how your code prevents the user from entering a decimal point

Comment: Um ... yeah... experiment.  `var foo = 14578.79; console.log(foo.toFixed(2)); foo = 14578; console.log(foo.toFixed(2))`

Comment: `<input type='text'/>` ← I love those. P.S: ... instead of `keypress` and `paste` etc... use just `input`

Comment: I just realized it does that with not allowing a decimal.  I found this on another Stack so didn't notice it till you pointed it out.

Also, am I old school with the slashes!

Comment: @Tibrogargan I understand how to use that in its basic sense, I said I do not understand how to incorporate it into my function.

Comment: `formatCurrency(parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2))`, but modify `formatCurrency` to ignore everything after the decimal.  Extra points: adding a check in for NaN first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent inserting empty "$" you need to check if number is empty and return the function. Here's a solution for you. You also need to allow "." in your `keypress` to allow users to add cents.

```
$('.money').blur(function(e){
        if($(this).val() == "") return;
    $(this).val(formatCurrency(this.value.replace(/[,$]/g,'')));
}).on('keypress',function(e){
    if(String.fromCharCode(e.which) != "." && !$.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) e.preventDefault();
}).on('paste', function(e){    
    var cb = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;      
    if(!$.isNumeric(cb.getData('text'))) e.preventDefault();
});
function formatCurrency(number){
    if(number == "") return;
    number = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
    var n = number.split('').reverse().join("");
    console.log(n);
    var n2 = n.replace(/\d\d\d(?!$)/g, "$&,");    
    return '$' + n2.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Check jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7scapsk9/

Comment: I just realized, this method does not allow, delete, backspace, tab, esc, CTRL-A, Home, End, arrow keys or enter.  Any idea to allow those functions?

Answer (score 1):

`parseFloat(value).toFixed(n)`

Where value is your number (can be string) and n is the number of decimals to show

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current `formatCurrency` function with this one:

```
function formatCurrency(number) {
    return (number != null && number != "") ? "$".concat(parseFloat(number).toFixed(2).toString()
        .split('').reverse().join("")
            .replace(/\d\d\d(?!$)/g, "$&,")
                .split('').reverse().join("")) : number;
}
```

If the number (or string that's a number) that's passed in isn't null, undefined, or an empty string it will parse the number into valid currency.